# Comparing two mixed-effects model, one of which was singular fit

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme

I wanted to compare two `lmer` models. One included a random intercept, the other included both random intercepts and random slopes. Although the output of `anova` showed the second model had more explanatory power, I'm not sure I should accept it due to the fact that it had a **boundary (singular) fit**. Could someone please advise whether the comparison was valid?

```
# Model 1
> lmer(satisfaction ~ status+sex+age+readmission + (1|area/id), hospSatisfaction, REML=FALSE)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: satisfaction ~ status + sex + age + readmission + (1 | area/id)
   Data: hospSatisfaction
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 63799.43  63857.15 -31891.71  63783.43     10049 
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 id:area  (Intercept)  3.426  
 area     (Intercept) 10.019  
 Residual              5.703  
Number of obs: 10057, groups:  id:area, 50; area, 3
Fixed Effects:
   (Intercept)    statuspublic            sexM             age  readmissionYes  
       48.4947        -13.9416         -7.0555          0.3078          5.1804  

# Model 2
> lmer(satisfaction ~ status+sex+age+readmission + (1+ readmission|area/id), hospSatisfaction, REML=FALSE)

boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: satisfaction ~ status + sex + age + readmission + (1 + readmission |  
    area/id)
   Data: hospSatisfaction
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 63700.71  63787.31 -31838.36  63676.71     10045 
Random effects:
 Groups   Name           Std.Dev. Corr
 id:area  (Intercept)     3.379       
          readmissionYes  1.709   0.04
 area     (Intercept)    10.006       
          readmissionYes  0.061   1.00
 Residual                 5.653       
Number of obs: 10057, groups:  id:area, 50; area, 3
Fixed Effects:
   (Intercept)    statuspublic            sexM             age  readmissionYes  
       48.4356        -13.9048         -7.0647          0.3081          5.1903  
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings

# Compare the two models
> anova(m_0, m_1)

Data: hospSatisfaction
Models:
m_0: satisfaction ~ status + sex + age + readmission + (1 | area/id)
m_0: satisfaction ~ status + sex + age + readmission + (1 + readmission | area/id)
    npar   AIC   BIC logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
m_0    8 63799 63857 -31892    63783                         
m_1   12 63701 63787 -31838    63677 106.71  4  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Never accept a model which is singular. I assume the reason this happened is because your random effects structure for the alternative model is too complex for your data to support.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnHemelstrand. So it was wrong to compare the two models at the first place because one of them was illegitimate (so to speak) for its singularity, wasn't it?

Comment: The singularity is (most likely) due to the correlation (Corr = 1.00) between the random intercept and slope at the *area* level. Perhaps another model specification (with a random slope) is appropriate instead. It'll help to explain the structure of the data; it'll even better to show some plots (of the response over readmission for some subjects). How many areas are there, what is readmission, etc?

Comment: Hi @dipetkov, `area` has 3 categories, `id` has 50 (integer) values and `readmission` is yes/no. To clarify, I'm not concerned about the singularity, but only the validity of the comparison because `anova` concluded that the second (singular) model was better. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried these forms for the random component: `(1 | id)` and `(1  + readmission | id)`? You'd have to make sure that the IDs are unique across areas. One way to do this is to concatenate the area & the subject ID: "{area}-{id}". Graphing your data will help you understand what's going on better.

Comment: I agree with dipetkov that graphing the data will tell you *why* this is happening and should be a pre-requisite to fitting mixed models anyway.

Comment: What kind of variable is satisfaction? What range of values can satisfaction take? And I think you should have a covariate that's about the severity of the condition for which the patients were hospitalized.

Comment: Thanks @dipetkov for suggesting alternative model forms to test. Because level 2 `id` (for hospitals) was nested in level 3 `area` (geographical locations) I thought I should include both of those upper level groupings in a multilevel model instead of just the level 2? In any case, when I compared the two models `(1|id)` and `(1|area/id)`, the latter was better, thus I used that as the base model before adding more level 1 predictors (`age`, `sex`, etc.). `satisfaction` is numeric from 0 to 100. Plotting `id` against `satisfaction` faceted by `area` showed different patterns of satisfaction

Comment: There is no fixed effect for area; I forgot to mention that you'd need to add `area` to the fixed component as clearly the area makes a difference. I'm not sure that modeling 3 areas as random makes sense. There are various aspects that you can take into consideration, in addition to the anovas.

Answer (score 4):

##### Singularity

As I noted in the comments, you should never accept a model which is singular. I assume the reason this happened is because your random effects structure for the alternative model is too complex for your data to support, which is a common issue in mixed model estimation. As dipetkov notes, the correlation between your slopes and intercepts in the random effects structure is perfect, indicating an issue already. The most common reason for this is because there simply is too little random effect variation to estimate, and this causes the model to explode because the determinant is close to zero:

> Chief among these convergence issues is the dreaded nonpositive
> definite covariance matrix, which often manifests when a variance is
> estimated at or below 0 or when the magnitude of the correlation
> between two random effects reaches or exceeds an absolute value of 1. --- McNeish & Bauer, 2022

Some articles on this subject that may be useful are found below. I provide two articles that specifically highlight this issue with respect to mixed models, and a book on linear algebra that has explanations of what singular matrices are (in case you need to know this info someday, the relevant discussion starts at Page 105). In any case, there is no reason you should compare these two models unless you modify them in some way, but even then I don't know if that alleviates the issue.

##### References

- Lay, D. C., Lay, S. R., & McDonald, J. (2016). Linear algebra and its applications (Fifth edition). Pearson.
- Matuschek, H., Kliegl, R., Vasishth, S., Baayen, H., & Bates, D. (2017). Balancing Type I error and power in linear mixed models. Journal of Memory and Language, 94, 305–315. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jml.2017.01.001
- McNeish, D., & Bauer, D. J. (2022). Reducing Incidence of nonpositive definite covariance matrices in mixed effect models. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 57(2–3), 318–340. https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2020.1830019

Comment: Thank you for the references on linear algebra and mixed-effects models. Will find time to digest them but I'm already lost just by reading the articles' titles!

Comment: The two articles I added are very readable for laymen and written by quant people who are well-versed in mixed models (the second paper is last authored by Bates who wrote `lme4`). The first book is also fairly readable but it is likely useful to read the rest of the book leading up to that point first.